Seemingly wrong output for a Fixed Effect Poisson Regression using pglm in R
I want to run a fixed effect regression with net migration being the response and gini index a predictor. I add some control variables. The data is from WDI.
Because the response in the data set has negative values, I added the minimum value + 1 to make it positive in order for the poisson regression to work.
library(WDI)
data <- WDI(
  country = c("AL", "AD", "AT", "BE", "BA", "HR", "EE", "FR", "GR", "IS",
              "IT", "LI", "MC", "ME", "PT", "SK", "ES", "SE", "GB", "UA",
              "BG", "CY", "DK", "FO", "FI", "DE", "IE", "XK", "LT", "LV",
              "MT", "MD", "NL", "MK", "NO", "PL", "RO", "SM", "SI", "CH",
              "TR", "RU", "BY"),
  indicator = c(
    "SI.POV.GINI", "SE.COM.DURS", "NY.GDP.PCAP.PP.KD","SL.UEM.TOTL.ZS","SP.POP.TOTL", "SM.POP.NETM"),
  start = 2004, 
  end = 2024    
)

write.csv2(data, "data.csv", row.names = FALSE) 
data <- read.csv("data.csv", header = TRUE, sep = ";", dec = ",")
attach(data)
View(data)
dim(data)
names(data)

#clean data
data <- data[3:10]
dim(data)
data <- na.omit(data)
dim(data)
summary(data)
View(data)

data$SM.POP.NETM <- data$SM.POP.NETM + 261814
summary(data)


#FE, Poisson
library(pglm) 
model1.FE = pglm(
  SM.POP.NETM ~ SI.POV.GINI + SE.COM.DURS + NY.GDP.PCAP.PP.KD + SL.UEM.TOTL.ZS + SP.POP.TOTL,
  data = data, family = poisson, model = "within"
)

summary(model1.FE)

The output seems wrong. If I specify a pglm random effect model I get some warnings.


Why do you have data$SM.POP.NETM + 261814 when in 2006 DEU (Germany) has -489056?

This approach of adding an arbitrary amount to make net migration positive and then trying to use Poisson regression to predict net migration is not going to make sense: in Poisson regression, $0$ is an important number, so shifting it will weaken the model.  In addition  migration is at least indirectly related to the size of a country so having many countries having close to  an arbitrary large number out of scale to the size of the country is going to destroy the model.
